# Base64 pulled from DB to blob

Tags: javascript, base64, blob

In general, is it faster to convert a base64 image to blob  and use that as the image source or just use the base64?  Would HTML rendering be faster to do this or should I just leave it?

Comment: I'd say that being able to leverage the browser cache is a factor that counts as well.

Comment: The base64 is stored into the database so I am doing requests for the information.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález base64 or blob has nothing to do with cache, those are never cached by the browser. It's wherever the ajax request can be loaded from cache or not

Comment: How about converting the base64 back to binary again on the server? The requested image will be ~3x larger with base64... if you are doing ajax request and it only contains the image itself then you could maybe do `responseType = "blob"` directly

Comment: @Endless I've been caching dynamically generated pictures for years, you just need to override the default HTTP headers generated by PHP. However, inline pictures have to be sent every time unless you cache the complete containing page.